# How to highlight marker dynamically with leaflet and leaflet draw

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-draw

I am trying to make a selection via drawing a rectangle (or any shape) with leaflet draw. The selected features should be highlighted. I saw that there are various functions within the leaflet source that could help (contains from Bounds class and _containsPoint from Poly) however I keep getting an error saying that layer does not have this function. I have tried putting the draw layer into a new variable by creating a new L.Polygon object and calling _containsPoint(), but this gives a similar error - saying that the function does not exist for that polygon.

```
var marker1 = L.marker([51.441767, 5.470247],{
    draggable: true
}).addTo(map);

var someLayerGroup = L.featureGroup();
marker1.addTo(someLayerGroup);

map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems,
        edit: false
    },
    draw: {
        marker: false,
        circlemarker: false,
        polyline: false,
        circle:  false,
        polygon: {
          allowIntersection: false,
          showArea: true
        }
    }
}));

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
    var layer2 = event.layer;
    var type = event.layerType;
    if(type==='rectangle'){
        //do rectangle specific actions
        someLayerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
            if(layer2.contains(layer)){
            //set style of the point
            layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#CCCC00'});
            }
        });
    }
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer2);
});
```

JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/2109/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- [`L.Layer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#layer) doesn't have a `.contains` method.
- [`L.Marker`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#marker) doesn't have a `.setStyle` method. (The blue default marker is in fact [a static image](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#icon-default-imagepath).)

Instead you can use [`CircleMarker`s](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlngbounds) and instantiate a [`L.LatLngBounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#latlngbounds) object with the corners of the drawn rectangle. Then check whether the point is contained in the bounds and change the point's marker style if yes.

```js
var marker1 = L.circleMarker([51.441767, 5.470247],{
  draggable: true
}).addTo(map);

[...]

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
  var layer2 = event.layer;
  var corners = [layer2._latlngs[0],layer2._latlngs[2]]  //retrieve corner of rectangle
  var type = event.layerType;
  if(type==='rectangle'){
    //do rectangle specific actions
    someLayerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if(L.latLngBounds(corners).contains(layer._latlng)){ //call .contains on an L.LatLngBounds object
        //set style of the point
        layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#CCCC00'});          //.setStyle of L.CircleMarker
      }
    });
  }
  drawnItems.addLayer(layer2);
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/2116/